# Why is "Ubisoft Connect" required in Just Dance 2022?

Tags: ubisoft-connect, just-dance-2022

I bought a physical game, *Just Dance 2022* for Switch. It was quite expensive.

Can anyone tell me what the account is for? I have some 30-day demo, no idea what. I have already paid a lot of money for the game.

Can *Just Dance 2022* be played in full without account/registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need an account to play the base game. You are probably referring to Just Dance Unlimited. The game **comes with some songs** when you buy it but if you want to get newer songs they have Just Dance Unlimited a subscription service to get new/more songs.

As per their website description:
*JUST DANCE® UNLIMITED is an online streaming service that grants you unlimited exclusive access to an ever-growing catalog of more than 600 of the best Just Dance songs from yesterday, today, and tomorrow. 24 Hour, 1 month, 3 month, and 12 month passes are available.*